# Unable to add cognito login provider using boto / aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, boto3

I am trying to create a cognito pool with facebook as the login provider using [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-identity.html#CognitoIdentity.Client.create_identity_pool)

This is the code snippet. I am able to successfully create the cognito pool, but the facebook login with the provided app id is not getting set even though I am passing it in.

```
  client.create_identity_pool(IdentityPoolName='my-pool-name',
  AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities=False,
  SupportedLoginProviders={'Facebook':511147282376301})
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try swapping out 'Facebook' for 'graph.facebook.com'?

If that doesn't work, a few clarifications would be helpful. By "is not getting set", do you mean the pool is created but you don't see the linked provider in the console? You aren't receiving any error, correct?

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that worked!!. There wasn't any document on what the provider name should be and i din't get any errors. And, yes the provider wasn't linked in the console. Changing "Facebook" -> 'graph.facebook.com' did the trick.

Comment: Fantastic. I noticed the same - we'll look into updating our docs to make what those fields should be more clear.

Comment: Docs have been updated to make this easier, thanks for heads up.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_CreateIdentityPool.html